# How to unfreeze a google sheets with nodejs and api

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm stucked with a gsheets i want to update because there are some rows and columns frozen.

I'm using the `google-spreadsheet` npm package but nothing in it to explicitly unfreeze a sheet.

I found this:

```js
await worksheet.updateProperties({
  gridProperties: {
    frozenColumnCount: 0,
    frozenRowCount: 0,
  }
});
```

and it's "shorthand"

```js
await worksheet.updateGridProperties({
  frozenColumnCount: 0,
  frozenRowCount: 0,
});
```

But in the two cases, it still say that i can't delete row frozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `google-spreadsheet` had a bug.

Method `updateProperties` and its shorthand `updateGridProperties` use internal `getFieldMask` method to determine which field are updated. And didn't manage correctly the gridProperties ones.

I opened a pull request to fix it: https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/pull/674

A workaround is to directly make your request with field hand-provided:

```js
worksheet._makeSingleUpdateRequest('updateSheetProperties', {
  properties: {
    sheetId: worksheet.sheetId,
    gridProperties: {
      frozenColumnCount: 0,
      frozenRowCount: 0,
    },
  },
  fields: 'gridProperties.frozenColumnCount,gridProperties.frozenRowCount',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in the case of `gridProperties` of `updateSheetProperties`, when you want to use `frozenColumnCount` and `frozenRowCount`, it is required to set `fields` as `gridProperties(frozenColumnCount,frozenRowCount)` or `gridProperties.frozenColumnCount,gridProperties.frozenRowCount`.

But, when I saw the original script of [google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet), only `gridProperties` is used as the value of `fields`. [Ref](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/master/src/lib/utils.ts#L3) In this case, all properties except for `frozenColumnCount` and `frozenRowCount` are reset. I guessed that this is the reason for your current issue of `it still say that i can't delete row frozen.`.

Unfortunately, I cannot know whether this situation is the author's expected situation. So, in this answer, I would like to propose the modified script using the current specification.

#### Modified script:

```
await worksheet.updateGridProperties({
  frozenColumnCount: 0,
  frozenRowCount: 0,
  ...worksheet.gridProperties,
});
```

- By this, at least, the error like  `You can't delete all the rows on the sheet.` was removed. But, when I confirm `worksheet.gridProperties`, only 2 properties of `rowCount` and `columnCount` are retrieved. So, in this case, 4 properties of `frozenColumnCount`, `frozenRowCount`, `rowCount`, and `columnCount` are used. But, in the case of `gridProperties`, there are 7 properties. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets?hl=en#GridProperties) So, the other 3 properties are reset. So, if in your actual Spreadsheet, when the properties of `hideGridlines`, `rowGroupControlAfter`, and `columnGroupControlAfter` are changed, please include them in the above object. By this, the request is run with the value of `fields` as `gridProperties`.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug of [google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet). If the users want to set the specific properties, I guess that updating the script of google-spreadsheet for giving manually the fields or updating the script of [getFieldMask](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/master/src/lib/utils.ts#L3) might be better.

#### Reference:

- [GridProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets?hl=en#gridproperties)